# Custom Listview in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

How can I customize a `ListView` in a Navigation Drawer, like the one [in the 2nd picture here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NavigationView** of Android Design Support Library (see: [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)).

With NavigationView, you don't have to use ListView any more. You can populate the drawer menu simply with `menu.xml`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```